# How to avoid using multiple SELECT statements to create a report

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm a beginner here so this is a stupid question. However, I'm trying to create a php webpage report which pulls out specific single stats from a mysql database.

Each stat is a single figure

- 'how many meetings held since records began,
- how many for past 12 months,
- how many since the start of this year,
- how many from the first of this month for example.

There are 6 questions like this for each of 5 departments - so 30 questions that require specific numbers as answers.

So I started to create a SELECT statement for each stat and I get the result I need, no problem - but it seems crazy to have that many select statements (it's a small database).

So I'm thinking that I should have one SELECT for each question like $sql = SELECT * FROM meetings and then apply my requirements within the ECHO statement - 'echo $sql where meeting date is between Jan 1st and Dec 31st and department equals finance' and the next question/requirement 'echo $sql where meeting date is between the first of this month and today and department equals finance' for example. (I know it's crude but hopefully conveys what I'm trying to get at.) Any help appreciated but what I'm looking for at this stage is a pointer as to the general process/method I need to ne looking at and learning. Thanks

Comment: Please provide some table definitions and example data + desired output (in text, not as images)

Comment: You might look at UNION ALL to combine resultsets from multiple queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maybe use functions

For example :

```php
function get_count($department, $number_month){
    $meetings = result_of_you_query; // SELECT * FROM meetings
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($meetings as $meeting) {
        if($meeting['department'] == $department){ // choose your department
            $month = date_format($meeting['date'] , "m"); 
            if($month == $number_month){ // choose the month
                $count = $count + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return $count;
}
```

And use it like this for all your questions

```php
$number = get_count("Finance", 12); // month in number
echo "Finance : You have $number meetings in December";
```

Comment: Thank you, the function route worked for me